# Javascript: Building an array with a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to take the contents of a variable and stick it into an array like so (I've tried to no avail):

First I get these values from a database and using php form into a hidden input:

```
{value: '1', name: 'name1'},{value: '2', name: 'name2'}
```

Then collect with javascript

```
document.getElementById("myelement").value
```

Then put the value

```
var meval = document.getElementById("myelement").value;
```

And then I try to build the data like so:

```
var data = {items: [meval]};
```

If I do this

```
var data = {items: [{value: '1', name: 'name1'},{value: '2', name: 'name2'}]};
```

it works but not the initial way with the variable. And I have to build the original data like that.

Comment: How are you generating the string (`"{value: '1', name: 'name1'},{value: '2', name: 'name2'}"`) server-side? Are you using PHP's `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval()` is evil! Use `JSON.parse()` instead.

```
var data = {items: JSON.parse('['+meval+']')};
```

If you have jQuery included on your website, you can do [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) which works better on older browsers.

Comment: @play: That's because your json is malformed. You should be outputting this from your database: `{"value": "1", "name": "name1"},{"value": "2", "name": "name2"}`. PHP's `json_encode()` will do that.

Comment: @play: Let me repeat myself: **That's because your json is malformed**. Once more: **YOUR JSON IS MALFORMED**. You should be outputting this from your database: `{"value": "1", "name": "name1"},{"value": "2", "name": "name2"}`.

Comment: I posted the comment before refreshing the page so I didn't see your comment. Thanks for your help. Sorry for the mix up. I tried now it gives me an "unexpected end of input" error

Comment: Then you forgot to close a bracket / quote

Comment: Thank you so very much. It was because of the echo some quotes were somehow being escaped.

Comment: Not all browsers support JSON.parse -
Only: Mozilla Firefox 3.5+, Microsoft Internet Explorer 8, Opera 10.5+, Webkit-based browsers (e.g. Google Chrome, Apple Safari) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#Native_JSON

Answer (score 2):

If your using a string, you can use eval() - but it's a bit naughty, as it introduces security & flow problems.

var meval = "[{value: '1', name: 'name1'},{value: '2', name: 'name2'}]";

var data = eval(meval);

Answer (score 2):

Eric is right, you're generally better off using JSON than arbitrary JavaScript literals. Currently your literal isn't valid JSON because it's not using double-quoted property names and string values. Use `json_encode` to get a JSON-compatible literal syntax.

You can fall back to `eval()` as in other answers when `JSON.parse` isn't available, but you will need to use extra brackets to ensure that `eval` knows that the leading `{` means an object literal and not a statement.

```
<?php
    function js($s) { // shortcut to save some typing
        echo json_encode($s, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT|JSON_HEX_APOS);
    }

    $data= array(name=>$row['name'], value=>$row['value']);
?>
<input type="hidden" id="data" value="<?php js($data); ?>"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var json= document.getElementById('data').value;
    var data= 'JSON' in window? JSON.parse(json) : eval('('+json+')');
</script>
```

Actually the `JSON_HEX` options in the `js` function allow literals to be output in a way that is equally valid in an HTML attribute or a `<script>` block, so you can indeed omit the hidden input and just say:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data= <?php js($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I solved the problem. Somehow through the echo in php something was being escaped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to eval that variable to turn it's content into the data structure:

```
var data = {items: [eval(meval)]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the items into a hidden input in this format:

```
"name1"."|"."name2"."|"."name3"... and so on
```

Then in JS:

```
var list = document.getElementById("yourelement").value;
var arrayOfStuff = list.split("|");
```

Now your JS array looks like this:

```
array() {
    [0] => "Name1"
    [1] => "Name2"
    [2] => "Name3"
    ... and so on
}
```